# How is CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY supposed to be set in a Rancher container?

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface, rancher

I'm working on a project requiring replacing `rancher-compose` with the `rancher` CLI.  At the same time, my Rancher installation was upgraded from 1.6.21 (IIRC) to 1.6.27.  The stacks deploy correctly when using `rancher-compose`.  When I deploy the stacks using the `rancher` CLI, all of the load balancer containers have errors similar to this in their logs:

```
6/5/2019 11:08:30 PM time="2019-06-06T03:08:30Z" level=error msg="Failed to initialize Kubernetes controller: KUBERNETES_URL is not set"
6/5/2019 11:08:30 PM 009921c0-3362-45a0-9ae1-3f2f4d06e7fatime="2019-06-06T03:08:30Z" level=info msg="Starting Rancher LB service"
6/5/2019 11:08:30 PM time="2019-06-06T03:08:30Z" level=info msg="Listening on /tmp/log.sock"
6/5/2019 11:08:30 PM time="2019-06-06T03:08:30Z" level=fatal msg="CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY is not set, fail to init of Rancher LB provider"
6/5/2019 11:08:32 PM + METADATA_ADDRESS=169.254.169.250
6/5/2019 11:08:32 PM + curl -s -f http://169.254.169.250/2015-12-19/self/service/uuid
6/5/2019 11:08:32 PM + /usr/bin/update-rancher-ssl
6/5/2019 11:08:32 PM + exec lb-controller --controller rancher --provider haproxy
```

When I use the `rancher-compose` CLI, the stacks are started without errors.

I have tried searching for anything related to the error, and the only results returned that include `CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY` seem to be old bug reports where the string turned up in dump output.  I tried searching for that string on the Rancher Web site and got an error stating

```
Unauthorized access to internal API. Please refer to https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542055
```

I have an API key and an environment API key configured through the Rancher GUI.  I set the `RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY` and `RANCHER_SECRET_KEY` environment values in my Linux shell, both using the API key and the environment API key, in turn.  Neither of those worked.  I also tried with the `RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY` and `RANCHER_SECRET_KEY` set using the API key values, and setting `CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY` and `CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_SECRET_KEY` using the environment API keys.  That also did not work.  I've also added code to the deployment script to pass an environment file to the CLI `up` command to set the `CATTLE_*` variables, which did not work.  I also modified the `docker-compose.yml` to add an `environment:` list, and that had no effect.

Where can I find documentation of what the `CATTLE_ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY` is supposed to be, and how to set it such that the fatal errors that are stopping the load balancer containers from starting cease to occur?

For bonus points, tell me how to get rid of the error message about `KUBERNETES_URL` not being set:  We're not using Kubernetes in this project *at all*, so I have *no* idea where *that* is coming from.

---

**EDIT**

```
$ rancher-compose --version
rancher-compose version v0.12.5
$ rancher --version
rancher version v0.6.13
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77
```

I also tried setting a `RANCHER_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable in my Linux shell, once to `1a5` and once to `Default`.  Neither of these changes made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is the `rancher` CLI is sensitive to command line parameter order in a way that `rancher-compose` is not:  With `rancher-compose`, this command line worked correctly:

```
rancher-compose --file docker-compose.yml --rancher-file rancher-compose.yml up pull
```

However, for the `rancher` CLI, the *commands* must be presented before the files:

```
rancher up pull --file docker-compose.yml --rancher-file rancher-compose.yml
```

This is not documented ***ANYWHERE***, and I got ***zero*** response when I posted my question on Rancher's Slack channel.  The only way I was able to fix the problem was through two weeks of trial and error debugging, and merely stumbling across the solution empirically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set also the rancher environment key?

```
RANCHER_ENVIRONMENT=xxx
```

And what is your rancher cli command that you are using?

*The kubernetes error it is pretty common, I think Rancher checks it before Cattle.*

Comment: The error *only* occurs in the load balancer containers, all of the other ones work correctly.  If a `RANCHER_ENVIRONMENT` key needed to be set, I would expect other containers to fail. As I stated in my question, the project I'm working on is moving from the `rancher-compose` CLI to the `rancher` CLI, and this error only occurs with the `rancher` CLI.